# Spinner setOnItemSelectedListener is not invoked

Tags: android, android-spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I checked the related questions to this problem and tried some of the suggestion but still it dosen't seem to execute the `setOnItemSelectedListener` event. Here is my activity code :

```
    private void init() {
       pays = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.pays_spinner);
       populatePays();
    }       

    List<String> list;
    public void populatePays(){
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        apiService = RestService.createService(SolarAPIService.class);
        Call<ArrayList<String>> call = apiService.listPays();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<String>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<String>> call, Response<ArrayList<String>> response) {
                    for(String pays: response.body()) {
                           list.add(pays);
                     }
                  }

                @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<String>> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });

   ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>
           (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
   dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource
           (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
   pays.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
   pays.setSelection(1);
   pays.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           nompays=pays.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                   "Selected Country : " + nompays, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           populateVille(nompays);
       }

       @Override
       public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

       }
   });
```

I would appreciate your help.
Thank you !

Comment: is your spinner populated with data?

Comment: yes my spinner get populated with data, Its just that When I try to select an element nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set spinner adapter after list has been filled.

```
private void init() {
    pays = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.pays_spinner);
    populatePays();
}

List<String> list;

public void populatePays() {
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    apiService = RestService.createService(SolarAPIService.class);
    Call<ArrayList<String>> call = apiService.listPays();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<String>> call,                    Response<ArrayList<String>> response) {
            for (String pays : response.body()) {
                list.add(pays);
            }
            setSpinnerAdapter();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<String>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

private void setSpinnerAdapter() {

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource
            (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    pays.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    pays.setSelection(1);
    pays.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            nompays = pays.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Selected Country : " + nompays, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            populateVille(nompays);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Nearly i spent one day to find this answer. Really a good job. Thanks @Patrick R